# I dropped the 'performance_schema' in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i use MySQL workbench only. I accidentally dropped that schema and whenever i try to access root host, it throws: "performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist" and now i cannot use MySQL workbench. I tried to remove the workbench and every "MySQL" file i can find and reinstall the workbench but it still got the same error.

Comment: i use window 10, i don't know where do the upgrade like that

Comment: You do it by opening a command window. Click the search bar and type `command`.

Comment: but i only install MySQL workbench, i don't have option "mysql_upgrade" like that

Comment: nevermind i found it, it is in my wamp file